# how to authenticate azure ad oauth2.0 web api in b2c clients

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a azure function app as httprequest (web api https://ph-bde-uat-ptsocfunapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Quote ) and deployed in azure.
Now I added oauth2.0 azure ad authentication and I am able to authenticate the api using postman with microsoft MFA. but how a third party clients will be authenticated this api in their Apps. (here the client app is developed using ruby).

I tried using azured ad oauth2.0 authentication with client id, client secret, authorize token, validate token and callback url and scope. but now I want this api to be authenticated using any 3rd party application. how we can authenticate the api in client apps or server to server authentication without user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

For server-to-server, use the [client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) flow.

"The OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow permits an app (confidential client) to use its own credentials, instead of impersonating a user, to authenticate when calling web resource, such as REST API. This type of grant is commonly used for server-to-server interactions that must run in the background, without immediate interaction with a user. These types of applications are often referred to as daemons or service accounts."

Comment: thank you for your reply and I gone through this but in my case  I registered my web api in azure but the client application is registered in aws or some other cloud. (my web api is consumed by different apps in different clouds).

Comment: You could use function keys by creating a key for each 3rd party client on the function app and then modifying your functions to use either admin or function authorization.

Comment: Here my requirement is to add OAuth2.0 to my azure function app http trigger. This authentication should be client credentials flow where other app or api will authenticate using clientid, client secret and tenant id. Not using user name and password. Please help here thanks in advance.

Comment: can I use service principal with authorization code flow as client_credentials here.